# Programing Rust to stop safety with systemctl

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety

I'm writing a very demanding program in rust that had variable Threads for processing very important data, and want to know if there is a way that i can send a signal to stop it with systemctl in a way that i can be sure that it is finishing it's dutties before stop, as its very demanding, uses http_request, and threads are variables I can not make an estimation of how much time i have to wait since signal sended until the process is dead.

In esscense, it is a daemon that is in a loop until a variable sets false, like this

```
loop {
    // Process goes here
    if !is_alive {
        break;
    }
}
```

What i'm doing right now is that the program is asking a "config.json" file if it is **"alive"**, but i think it's not the best way because i don't know when the program stops, just can see that is stoping, but not how much is going to last, and if i do this way, systemctl is going to show the service alive, even if i shuted it down manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to experiment with Systemd service behavior, I would take a look at the Systemd documentation. In this case, I would direct you to the section about [`TimeoutStopSec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#TimeoutStopSec=).

According to the documentation, you can disable any timeout on systemd stop commands with `TimeoutStopSec=infinity`. This combined with actually handling the `SIGTERM` signal that systemd uses by default should do the trick.

Furthermore, there is the [`KillSignal`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.kill.html#KillSignal=) option by which you can specify the signal that is sent to your program to stop it or [`ExecStop`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStop=) to specify a program to run in order to stop your service.

With these you should be able to figure it out, I hope.